# How can / How should I add extra columns to the google shopping feed?

Tags: google, advertising, shopping

We are using google shopping to export (product) data to Google for Shopping Ads using this spec https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7052112. The spec outlines all the required fields, but does not really toch on the subject of `adding extra fields`. We have now added some field as `c:customfield` in line with the google spec where most fields are named with a leading `g:`... and we have replaced this with a leading `c:` to mark the fields as custom. What is the accepted manner of adding extra fields?

**Question**: How can / How should I add extra columns to the google shopping feed?

This is how it looks like now

```
<item>
        <c:postorpackage>package</c:postorpackage>
        <g:age_group>adult</g:age_group>
        <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
        <g:condition>new</g:condition>
        <g:gender>male</g:gender>
```